# C# get string from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am just a noob in C#, and I've got this question to ask you.

I have here a form that asks for login details. It has two textfields:

1. Username
2. Password

What I want is to ***get the strings entered in that textfields.***

I am not yet familiar with the methods in C#..(in java, getString method is used). What could be the "equivalent" method here in C#?

Comment: .NET has good documentation. So please read documentation first and if you really cant find something then ask. I'am telling this, because later you will ask for example how to change align of text and so on.

Comment: thank you for the advice. i am currently reading this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx.. i hope to hear more advice from you to help me with c#.. :)

Comment: you reading tutorial about console application - really good starting point to learn syntax of c#. From your question I guess you trying to learn winforms. [Here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/random.htm) is quite nice tutorial to start creating winform apps. In tutorial is the answer to your question :). Good luck.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In C#, unlike java we do not have to use any method. TextBox property `Text` is used to get or set its text.

**Get**

```
string username = txtusername.Text;
string password = txtpassword.Text;
```

**Set**

```
txtusername.Text = "my_username";
txtpassword.Text = "12345";
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I was not so much clarified with the answers returned. and also I would like to keep this question on my account so that I will not ask google, and at the same time, this serves as my journal(sort of) about my new learnings.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) control has a [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk.aspx) property that you can use to get (or set) the text of the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

When using MVC, try using ViewBag. The best way to take input from textbox and displaying in View.

Answer (score 3):

I show you this with an example:

```
string userName= textBox1.text;
```

and then use it as you wish

Comment: Make sure your code looks like it. It increases your answer acceptance. Use 4 space before code as i did to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

if in string:

```
string yourVar = yourTextBoxname.Text;
```

if in numbers:

```
int yourVar = int.Parse(yourTextBoxname.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get value of textbox

```
   string username = TextBox1.Text;
   string password = TextBox2.Text;
```

to set value of textbox

```
  TextBox1.Text = "my_username";
   TextBox2.Text = "12345";
```