# How to return answer from textbox

Tags: c#

I have some code where a user inputs some information into a textbox and I want to return that information as a string that I can access from other places in the code. (subquestion - I've searched everywhere - what's the name for blocks of code under something like "Private void")

```
private string SearchJobNoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string sSearchJobNo = SearchJobNoTextBox.Text;
  return sSearchJobNo;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# get string from textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696941/c-sharp-get-string-from-textbox)

Comment: Event do not return values. But the Text property is there for anyone to use. so the question is:  __who__ shall use it and __when__? With every keystroke as you have now? or when `Leaving` the TextBox? Or when pressing enter? Or clicking a Button..?

Comment: @bkribbs I saw that but let me have another look. Also, what is an appropriate name for a block of code under "private string xxx" (rookie question). I know it's a type but is there a more specific name?

Comment: Your code block as written is called an 'error' as it looks like an event but, as I wrote, these do not return values. Tell us what you want to happen!

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice this was in an event handler. Yeah when do you want this to occur? You need to use these values on a button being clicked or something.

Comment: @TaW People will use it to enter Job numbers that they are searching for. There may be multiple search criteria though (like different plants), so I created a separate "private string" for each textbox where users can enter data.

Comment: @bkribbs yes there's a search button, so I just need the full textbox entry converted to a string.

Comment: _so I created a separate "private string"_ It makes little sense to do that, as the Text properties are there already and the textboxes are private. So you can use them in building a search condtion __just like you would use your strings__! Storing them somewhere else might make sense if they have to be validated and restored when the user enters crap, but for the time being, just use textbox1.Text just as a string..

Comment: Then you would just need a button handler and have that handler use all the values. You don't need to save them to another string somewhere else first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method handling `TextChanged` event can't return anything, it should be void.

Also - you can access this textbox text anywhere in your form class. If you need to get it somewhere outside your form - you can create public (or internal - depending on scope you need to access it) method (or property) returning it.

Something like

```
public string SearchJobNo
{
    get { return SearchJobNoTextBox.Text; }
}
```

Then you will be able to access this value as `yourform.SearchJobNo`

And answer on your subquestion: name for blocks of code under something like "Private void" - is "method".