# How get String from Textbox in windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell-4.0

i am an SCCM administrator ,so i am planing to make some automation with powershell using GUI

so i need to input some values from windowsform. can anyone help me to get value from texbox

```html
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

#Creating Form
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,500) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"



#Creating Label
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Enter collection Name"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

#Creating Teextbox
$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 
 
 #How to take input from the Textbox here???
 #so that i can pass the input string to powershell commands
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# get string from textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696941/c-sharp-get-string-from-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

To set a value in C# (e.g. the text from a textbox) you do it the same way you get it!
Here is an example:

```
//To set the text in a textbox
textBox1.Text = "some text";

//To get the text from a textbox
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
//The Messagebox will contain the text from the textbox
```

Hope this helped you! :)